# Nginx rewrites mith map module

Tags: nginx

I'm using nginx and its map module to do some rewrites.
Probably I don't understand nginx (and the map module...)

I want do rewrite links from

```
http://myDomain?forum=1&redirect=1
http://myDomain?forum=2&redirect=1
http://myDomain?forum=3&redirect=1
```

to

```
http://myDomain/firstforum/overview
http://myDomain/secondforum/overview
http://myDomain/thirdforum/overview
```

I configured a map like:

```
map $arg_forum $redirect_to {
    forum=1 /firstforum;
    forum=2 /secondforum;
    forum=3 /thirdforum;
}
```

Now I try something like:

```
set $redirect_args $args;

if ($args ~* "^redirect=(\d+)&forum=(\d+)") {
    set $foo $redirect_to?$redirect_args;
    set $args '';
    rewrite ^.*$ /myDomain/$foo/overview permanent;
}
```

Can someone help me? How did I get the 'content' of the map?